# Are there rules for the positioning of clitic pronouns?

Tags: pronouns

Are there rules for the positioning of clitic pronouns? Is there a preference between “poterlo dire” and “poter dirlo”, apart from how it sounds within a given sentence?

Comment: 'poterlo dire' sarebbe interessante, ma per 'poter dirlo' si dovrebbe disporre di un contesto piuttosto ampio.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Academia della Crusca explanation](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/posizione-pronomi-atoni):

> There are five cases in which pronouns form a single word with the
>   previous item:
>
> 1. with an imperative verb (e.g., *dimmi, ascoltalo, parglagli*)
> 2. with a gerund or in the past tense (e.g., *vedendola, avendomi detto*)
> 3. with a past participle with the function of the subordinate clause (e.g., *giuntami notizia dell'accaduto, andai subito da lei*)
> 4. with a present participle (almost only with the reflective one, e.g., *confacentesi*)
> 5. with an infinitive (e.g., *andarci, proporgli*). Just this case with the infinitive presents some peculiarities, one of which answers your
>      question. When the infinitive is preceded by a modal verb (*sapere,
>      volere, potere, dovere*, etc.), an unstressed pronoun might be combined
>      with the action verb or with the modal verb (e.g., *lo posso dire/posso
>      dirlo*). In many cases, the freedom of position of an unstressed
>      pronoun allows using it both as a proclitic and as an enclitic (e.g.,
>      *non riesco a vederlo/non lo riesco a vedere*).

Besides, [Enciclopedia dell'Italiano](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-modali_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/) adds the following:

> If a modal verb consists of two infinitives, you may have three choices: the pronoun can be in the initial position (*lo devo poter fare*), joined with the first infinitive (*devo poterlo fare*), or with the second infinitive (*devo poter farlo*).

Hence, both phrases in your question are grammatically correct.

Answer (score 3):

The following explanation has been adapted from *Grande grammatica italiana di consultazione. Vol. 1*, pages 572-574, which is also where all the examples are from:

A clitic can move from the infinitive of the subordinate clause to the verb of the main clause (which is usually done in Tuscan and central-southern Italian) if

- the subject of the main clause is identical to the implicit subject of the
  subordinate clause and
- the verb of the main clause belongs to one of the following classes:

**Modal Verbs**

> *Mario vuole farlo da solo.* / *Mario lo vuole fare da solo.* — Mario wants to do it on his own.
>
> *Antonio deve comprarlo.* / *Antonio lo deve comprare.* — Anthony has to buy it.
>
> *Frederico può mangiarli.* / *Frederico li può mangiare.* — Frederick can eat them.
>
> *Ugo sa prepararlo.* / *Ugo lo sa preparare.* — Hugo knows how to prepare it.

The modal use of *sapere* in the last example needs to be distinguished from its non-modal use, in which it takes an infinitive complement introduced by the preposition *di*. The latter does *not* permit clitic climbing:

> Ugo sa di comprarlo. — Hugo knows that he is buying it.
>
> *Ugo lo sa di comprare.

**Aspectual Verbs**

> *La mamma comincerà a cucirla domani.* / *La mamma la comincerà a cucire domani.* — Mom will start sewing it tomorrow.
>
> *Carlo finisce di dipingerlo oggi.* / *Carlo lo finisce di dipingere oggi.* — Charles will finish painting it today.
>
> *Sandro continua ad amarla.* / *Sandro la continua ad amare.* — Alex continues to love her.
>
> *Andrea sta per comprarla.* / *Andrea la sta per comprare.* — Andrew is about to buy it.

**Motion Verbs**

> *Piero andò/venne/tornò a chiamarlo.* / *Piero lo andò/venne/tornò a chiamare.* — Peter went/came/returned to call him.

**Conative Verbs (Only Marginally)**

> *Marco tenta di studiarlo.* / *?Marco lo tenta di studiare.* — Marcus is trying to study it.
>
> *Elio ha cercato di raggiungerlo.* / *?Elio lo ha cercato di raggiungere.* — Elliot has tried to reach it.
>
> *Anselmo prova a costruirlo.* / *?Anselmo lo prova a costruire.* — Anselm is trying to build it.

In the following examples, clitic climbing is *not* possible:

> *Aldo ha deciso di leggerlo.* — Aldo has decided to read it.
>
> **Aldo lo ha deciso di leggere.*
>
> *Maria dice di scriverla domani.* — Mary says to write it tomorrow.
>
> **Maria la dice di scrivere domani.*
>
> *Luisa ha promesso di spedirla.* — Louise has promised to send it.
>
> **Luisa la ha promesso di spedire.*
>
> *Carlo vuole che lo compri.* — Charles wants me/him/her to buy it.
>
> **Carlo lo vuole che compri.*