# "Venire a prenderti" vs. "venirti a prendere"

Tags: verbs, sentences, word-order

L'altro giorno, parlando con la mia ragazza, mi sono imbattuto in una frase che sembra pronunciabile in due diversi modi (probabilmente uno dei due è errato a livello formale):

- Vorrei venire a prenderti alle 18:00;
- Vorrei venirti a prendere alle 18:00.

Potreste darmi qualche delucidazione in merito alla validità delle suddette affermazioni? Grazie!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avevo posto una domanda simile qui: [Are there rules for the positioning of clitic pronouns?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/15/are-there-rules-for-the-positioning-of-clitic-pronouns)
Il succo della risposta ottenuta e di altro che avevo verificato è che sono corrette entrambe, e che la differenza è praticamente solo in come suona la frase (soprattutto in un contesto più ampio in cui una delle due formulazioni potrebbe essere più chiara dell'altra).

Answer (score 3):

- Vorrei venire a prenderti alle 18:00;
- Vorrei venirti a prendere alle 18:00.

Sono rispettivamente:

- Vorrei venire a prendere te alle 18:00;
- Vorrei venire te a prendere alle 18:00.

Si possono usare sia l'una che l'altra, nel secondo caso il "te" è messo prima di "a prendere" e dopo "venire", ma si riferisce sempre al secondo verbo... la seconda si usa raramente, ma si usa più in frasi del tipo:

"Vorrei vederti fare gli esercizi"

ovvero "Vorrei vedere te fare gli esercizi", dove il "te" si riferisce al primo verbo!

Saluti

Answer (score -2):

'venire a prenderti' è la forma corretta, evita l'altra, soprattutto se arrivi in ritardo; potrebbe diventare pretesto per una discussione.

Comment: Cosa ti fa dire che solo una delle forme è corretta?

Comment: @DaG, perché 'venire a prenedere te' è italiano moderno, mentre 'venire te a prendere' non lo è.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis *Fammi dire* che la tua risposta non è accettabile. Certo *vengoti a prendere* è antiquato, ma *venirti a prendere* è piuttosto diffuso. La differenza è nella presenza dell'infinito.

Comment: e comunque *ti vengo a prendere* è parimenti diffuso :-)

Comment: Scusate ma *vengoti a prendere* è bellissimo e dovremmo usarlo più spesso :)