# Lo puoi/puoi lo fare così?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

> Lo puoi fare così ?

Versus

> Puoi lo fare così ?

Which one is correct? Are both version correct? If so, is there any differences or preferences between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible correct forms: your first one (*Lo puoi fare così?*) and the one where the pronoun *lo* is appended to the infinitive *fare*, yielding *farlo*: *Puoi farlo così?*

The preference among the two forms is mostly subjective and euphonic.

(Something more can be found in the answer to a question that touches on a similar topic: «[Are there rules for the positioning of clitic pronouns?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/15/are-there-rules-for-the-positioning-of-clitic-pronouns)»)

Comment: So no, the second "Puoi lo fare così" is not correct :)