# Quando usare il pronome unito alla fine dei verbi?

Tags: verbs, pronouns

Ho visto molte volte l'uso di pronomi insieme a verbi, come in "esserci", "portarmi" etc.
E ho pure visto, ed imparato, anche "mi portare", come, per esempio, nella seguente frase:

- Elberich, non *mi portare* a casa stasera, preferisco restare qui.

Sarei interssato a sapere perché dovrei preferire la frase testé scritta piuttosto che la seguente?

- Elberich, non *portarmi* a casa stasera, preferisco restare qui.

Comment: “Mi portare” da solo non ha senso. Intendi forse casi come “mi devi portare” e “devi portarmi”? Se capisco bene la tua domanda, potrebbe avere già una risposta qui: [“Are there rules for the positioning of clitic pronouns?”](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/15/are-there-rules-for-the-positioning-of-clitic-pronouns)

Comment: @DaG E perché non ha senso? Uno potrebbe dire 'non mi portare a casa' oppure 'non portarmi a casa'. Credo il senso della domanda sia proprio questo.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider: Infatti, è quello che penso anch'io. Dicevo, in maniera forse non molto chiara, che non ha senso “da solo”, per chiedere un chiarimento, un esempio di frase a cui si riferisce la domanda.

Comment: @DaG Sì, sono d'accordo. Ora, nel pieno spirito della filosofia di Stackexchange, cercò di migliorare la domanda. Just a second.

Comment: Enthusiast, potresti chiarire la domanda? Vuoi sapere quale delle due forme preferire quando sono intercambiabili o vuoi sapere quando è possibile aggiungere il pronome alla fine del verbo nel linguaggio moderno senza sembrare usciti da un libro del 1800?

Comment: Voglio soltanto sapere se c'è una regola per quando si devo aggiungiare il pronome o se è una scelta mia.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sebbene ci potrebbe essere una qualche preferenza stilistica o grammaticale di cui non sono a conoscenza, quello che posso dirti nella mia esperienza di madrelingua è che non c'è alcuna differenza nell'uso comune delle due forme.

La forma contratta è ***leggermente*** preferita nel parlato, e viceversa nello scritto, ma sono entrambe valide.

Comment: Credo che la domanda sia stata interpolata (seppur in buona fede) da Elberich Schneider nel suo edit. Guarda la [cronologia delle revisioni](http://italian.stackexchange.com/posts/5915/revisions), per quel che capisco, salvo l'errore, la domanda era più generale, e volta a capire quando è possibile usare il pronome alla fine del verbo (ad esempio non in "Elberich, sentomi male!"), piuttosto che a capire quale delle due forme preferire quando sono intercambiabili; per come è posta adesso decisamente concordo

Comment: Posporre la particella pronominale in ogni situazione era un vezzo della lingua scritta (*dicesi*, *vendesi*, *sentomi male* eccetera). Ci sono casi però in cui la posposizione è obbligatoria, per esempio con l'imperativo: *portalo con te*, *datemi un martello*. Nel caso in esame, cioè l'imperativo negativo (seconda persona singolare, reso con l'infinito), le due forme sono effettivamente intercambiabili.