# Raddoppiamento delle consonanti in parole composte: esiste qualche regola?

Tags: orthography, compounds

Nella formazione di parole composte ho osservato che molte volte si raddoppiano consonanti che sono semplici nei vocaboli da cui provviene la parola composta. Per esempio:

> - così + detto --> cosiddetto
> - sopra + tutto --> soprattutto

La mia domanda è: esiste qualche regola per sapere quando si devono raddoppiare queste consonanti?

Comment: Ottima domanda! Potrei giurare di aver letto una regola per questo da qualche parte quand'ero a scuola, ma non riesco proprio a ricordarmi dove. Con un po' di fortuna qualcuno riuscirà a reperirla...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

È un esempio del *raddoppiamento sintattico, o fonosintattico*, che menzionavo rapidamente [qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5998/dammi-un-bacio-how-to-construct-dammi-from-dare/5999#5999) e che nell'italiano standard si verifica anche nei casi di grafia non unita (cioè, si scrive “vado a casa” ma si pronuncia “vado accasa”) con la differenza appunto che è reso esplicito solo nelle univerbazioni.

Si verifica dopo le parole tronche con l'accento indicato (dà, così, né, città...) e alcuni monosillabi: i sostantivi, aggettivi e pronomi (forti) monosillabi, ma anche altri, come “a” e “da” (cf. “addio” e “dabbene”), e alcune altre parole. C'è una descrizione completa nella [voce sul raddoppiamento](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/raddoppiamento/) dell'enciclopedia Treccani.

Alcuni dizionari specificano esplicitamente o con accorgimenti grafici se una parola dà luogo al raddoppiamento dopo (o in rari casi prima) di sé. Per esempio, la voce [“sopra”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sopra/) del Treccani specifica “(radd. sint., come prep.)”, cioè solo quando viene usata come preposizione (“sopra la tavola”) non come avverbio (“vado sopra ma tu resta qui”). Nel DOP è invece indicato con un piccolo segno “+” dopo (o prima) della parola: vedi per es. [“così”](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=75220&r=972).

Sottolineo che qui si parla dell'italiano standard: in molte altre varietà dell'italiano alcuni raddoppiamenti canonici non si verificano (per esempio “da” raddoppia quasi solo in Toscana) o se ne verificano di non standard (in alcune parlate romane, per esempio, in parole come “chiesa” e “sedia” la consonante iniziale si raddoppia anche dopo l'articolo: “lacchiesa”, “lassedia”).

Comment: Quindi, se cerco i vocaboli nel DOP, il raddoppiamento si deve fare dopo le parole che hanno questo piccolo segno "+" dopo la loro trascrizione fonetica, no?

Comment: Esattamente, @Charo.