# Raddoppio consonante iniziale

Tags: pronunciation

Nella pronuncia italiana, in alcuni casi la consonante all'inizio della parola viene pronunciata come se fosse doppia.
Esempio: vado a **C**asa.

Suppongo che questa cosa abbia un nome, e che ci sia una qualche regola per spiegare quando la consonante viene raddoppiata... qualcuno sa queste cose?

Ho notato che vengono raddoppiate le consonanti iniziali di parole che si trovano dopo una parola monosillabica che non sia un articolo o un pronome. Almeno questo dagli esempi a cui sono riuscita a pensare.

- lei non fa **C**aso a queste cose
- non è **V**ero
- sono partito da **C**asa presto (però la casa, la mia casa... sono pronunciate come C singole. Pure la variante toscana "la mi' casa", non raddoppia)
- è già **T**ardi
- arriverà a **B**reve
- non è **N**é **C**arne né **P**esce (alla terza o quarta volta che provavo a pronunciarla, non so nemmeno io dove mi viene naturale mettere le doppie in questa frase ^^)

Esempi con pronomi:

- e tu **C**he **N**e sai? (la S non raddoppia. Forse perché "che ne" formano un gruppo che suona già come bisillabico alla pronuncia? O perché ne è un pronome?)
- la vedo
- te l'ho **D**etto mille volte (la L non raddoppia, la D sì)

Scusate la lunghezza del post, mi ero messa a pensare a più esempi possibili per capire come funzioni... e alla fine ho pensato di chiedere qua.

PS: sto parlando di pronuncia italiana "standard", nelle varie pronunce locali alcuni di questi esempi non sono validi

Comment: È un fenomeno noto come “raddoppiamento (fono)sintattico”. Anche se apparentemente la domanda era su un'altra cosa, [qui troverai](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8186/raddoppiamento-delle-consonanti-in-parole-composte-esiste-qualche-regola) un punto di partenza su quello che ti interessa.

Comment: Non mi erano venuti in mente esempi con parole con più sillabe, tipo città. Grazie mille!

Comment: Ritieni che la risposta a quell'altra domanda risponda anche a questa? Se sì, si potrà chiudere questa per non lasciarne di aperte quando chi le ha poste è soddisfatto. Se invece ritieni che ci sia qualche aspetto che rimane senza risposta lo potresti mettere in evidenza?

Comment: Direi che un mix della risposta a quella domanda e a questa https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5998/dammi-un-bacio-how-to-construct-dammi-from-dare/ , diano la risposta alla mia domanda.


Quindi... devo chiuderla? come si fa?

Comment: @DaG: Sei d'accordo che forse è una buona idea chiudere questa domanda?

Comment: @Charo: Visto che LisaD sembra soddisfatta, direi di sì.