# What's the origin of 'fammi' and 'dimmi'?

Tags: grammar

Am I right in thinking that 'fammi' and 'dimmi' are just compounds of the imperatives 'fa' and 'di' + 'mi', and the double M is purely for euphony?
Or do they have another origin?

Can this construction be applied to any other verbs? (There's 'stammi', of course.)

Comment: Even though the specific subject was the analogous word *dammi*, I believe the most of this could help you: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5998/dammi-un-bacio-how-to-construct-dammi-from-dare Am I right?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: @DaG Yes, that covers it! Thanks.

Comment: Should this be closed as duplicate?

Comment: I am sorry to have closed your first question as a duplicate: it was a good question! But I think this is the way to make it most useful for possible future readers, without letting the reference buried in the comments. I hope you will continue to ask interesting questions here.